# Country 한자 characters used in headlines

Tags: hanja, place-names

I just ran across the 한자 伊(저 이) used in [a headline](http://news.naver.com/main/read.nhn?mode=LSD&mid=shm&sid1=104&oid=003&aid=0007557933) to mean "Italy".  It's the first time I'd seen it, so I was wondering if there are other characters actively used to represent countries in headlines and newspaper articles.  The ones I know are:

- 韓 South Korea
- 北 North Korea
- 中 China
- 日 Japan
- 美 USA
- 英 UK
- 伊 Italy
- 佛 France (not sure if still used in headlines?)

Are there any others that may be used?

Comment: By France, I think you mean 法，and 意  for Italy

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy 불어 (French language) is 佛語 in the dictionary, and 伊 is used in the article I linked to.

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy Actually, 法 and 意 seem to be used I Chinese, but Korean appears to use different characters for these countries.

Comment: 法，and 意 had been used to express France and Italy, but they are very old fashioned, used in more than 50 years ago. In these days, examples in this question are used.

Answer (score 3):

Other examples not posted here:

- 俄/露 -> Russia
- 蒙 -> Mongolia
- 濠洲 -> Australia
- 葡 -> Portugal

Comment: 俄 is sometimes used but 露[ro] is more broadly used. Others are used in headlines frequently. Especially, 濠洲(호주) is used much more frequently  than its original name, Australia.

Answer (score 3):

Some online resources I was able to find:

[Blog: Country names in Hanja](http://nojas2856.blog.me/10051299392)

[Blog: Country/City names in Hanja](http://blog.naver.com/yunbh66/140004243085)

[Blog: Continent/Countyr/Place names in Hanja](http://blog.naver.com/heeyuen2003/60049461289)

The most comprehensive list is in the Korean Wikipedia:

[List of Hanja characters for country names](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EB%82%98%EB%9D%BC_%EC%9D%B4%EB%A6%84%EC%9D%98_%ED%95%9C%EC%9E%90_%ED%91%9C%EA%B8%B0_%EB%AA%A9%EB%A1%9D)

For Italy specifically, it seems to the Hanja used in the transliteration of Italy into Chinese (it looks like there is more than one character, may be the one mentioned in the question is the most common one?):

> 이탈리아 :    伊太利(이태리), 伊太利亞(이태리아), 以太利(이태리), 意大利(의대리)

This is the list of Hanja abbreviations for country names (on quick skimming of the article it looks like most of the abbreviations are just the first Hanja character for the country name given in the list in the article above)

[Hanja abbreviation for country names](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EB%82%98%EB%9D%BC_%EC%9D%B4%EB%A6%84%EC%9D%98_%ED%95%9C%EC%9E%90_%EC%95%BD%EC%B9%AD)

> 이탈리아: 이태리(일본어: 伊太利 イタリー, 일본어: 伊太利亜 イタリア)의 첫글자를 딴 伊(이)

Another list that might be useful:
[Transliteration](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EC%9D%8C%EC%97%AD%EC%96%B4)

> 이태리(伊太利) - 이탈리아

Answer (score 3):

That characters can be interst for someone, recent 10 years no more used except S/N korea, japan, china, USA, UK. sometime, France was writed as 佛, but many of cases write 프(korean character). Russia also used as 露 in some news, kinda old-fashion-company. other 한자s was never used now.

I am 19 korean and honestly first saw in this article how can wrtie italy, mongol, austrailia, portugal in 한자. I never saw when I was growing up in school.

In the first place, that reason write country as 한자, old people got not used to english and western world, so they tranlslate its pronunciation, write fit in korean.

For example, they said russia as 'no-seo-a' that very koreantic pronuciation. But these day all of young korean say it 'russia'. In news nowdays russia write '러' don't use 한자. If someone question to teenager, twenties korean, do you know what is 'no-seo-a'?, 80% would say no. Do you know what means 露?, 10% would say yes. It's very old way.

Answer (score 3):

Just adding some established usages to the list:

- 比(비) for the Philippines. [韓-比 FTA 추진…11월 체결 목표](http://biz.chosun.com/site/data/html_dir/2019/04/17/2019041702910.html)
- 西(서) for Spain. [西 언론 '이강인 준우승, 세계는 그의 발 앞에 있다'](http://news.chosun.com/site/data/html_dir/2019/06/23/2019062300297.html)
- 蘇(소) for the Soviet Union. [승인 받자마자 유엔 가입 신청… 蘇 거부권 행사로 무산](http://news.chosun.com/site/data/html_dir/2018/09/19/2018091900104.html)
- 越(월) for Vietnam. [北·越 우호 행보 계속…리용호, 베트남 외교관 만찬 주최](http://news.chosun.com/site/data/html_dir/2019/03/10/2019031000565.html)
- 印(인) for India. [모디 印 총리 재집권 눈앞…‘7%대 성장’ 모디노믹스 탄력받을까](http://news.chosun.com/site/data/html_dir/2019/05/23/2019052303771.html)
- 印尼(인니) for Indonesia. [일본에 연거푸 당한 한국셔틀콕, 印尼오픈 빈작에 그쳐](http://news.chosun.com/site/data/html_dir/2019/07/20/2019072001012.html)
- 泰(태) for Thailand. [泰군부, 전격 쿠데타 선언… 과도정부 해산](http://news.chosun.com/site/data/html_dir/2014/05/23/2014052300153.html)
- 和(화) for the Netherlands. [朴대통령, 和국왕 오찬에서 '메뉴판'에 메모한 사연은](http://news.chosun.com/site/data/html_dir/2014/03/30/2014033001530.html)

And also note for continent names in headlinese:

- 歐(구) for Europe. [도요타 歐에서 하이브리드 질주…내연기관 퇴출 준비 착착](http://it.chosun.com/site/data/html_dir/2018/07/13/2018071300724.html)
- 亞(아) for Asia, and
- 阿(아) for Africa. ['亞 최강' 이란, '阿 복병' 모로코 맞아 자존심 지킬까](http://news.chosun.com/site/data/html_dir/2018/06/15/2018061501857.html)

Answer (score 2):

獨(독) for Germany as well. 
However, it's worth noting that 露(로) is not used much any more, and you will likely see 러 as an abbreviation for Russia.